# Are there any other options to implement "HttpContext.GetServiceProviders()" & "Http.Context.IsProviderSupported(provider)"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
 public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("~/signin")]
        public IActionResult SignIn() => View("SignIn", HttpContext.GetExternalProviders());
        [HttpPost("~/signin")]
        public IActionResult SignIn([FromForm] string provider)
        {
            // Note: the "provider" parameter corresponds to the external
            // authentication provider choosen by the user agent.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(provider))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            if (!HttpContext.IsProviderSupported(provider))
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            // Instruct the middleware corresponding to the requested external identity
            // provider to redirect the user agent to its own authorization endpoint.
            // Note: the authenticationScheme parameter must match the value configured in Startup.cs
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, provider);
        }

        [HttpGet("~/signout"), HttpPost("~/signout")]
        public IActionResult SignOut()
        {
            // Instruct the cookies middleware to delete the local cookie created
            // when the user agent is redirected from the external identity provider
            // after a successful authentication flow (e.g Google or Facebook).
            return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
               SalesforceAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
```

`(!HttpContext.IsProviderSupported(provider)) & HttpContext.GetExternalProviders()`- produces an error in Visual Studio 2017 , but it worked in Visual Studio Code

I am not sure why it is doing this, but any help with these issues are much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question for improving styling which will be more readable your question.

Comment: @EliasMP Thank you for pointing that out, I see that the code is edited. My question is " Are there any other options to implement "HttpContext.GetServiceProviders()" & "Http.Context.IsProviderSupported(provider)"? I am using ASP.Net Core 1.1 in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017

Comment: You are welcome @Cherokee. Hoping one of the other members could help you to find de solution.